# How the starting command execution time is accessed by the use of tracing command in CQLSH

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

I want to get the starting command execution time using cqlsh, I have used the tracing on in cqlsh, but my table has about 50,000 records so tracing logs report is very long and is passed away so that's why I can't get the starting time of the query execution but ending time is displayed.

Can anyone please tell me how can I access the starting point of the tracing report or can I store this tracing log report to some file from where I can access the starting time stamp?

I will also welcome to any other solution to my problem. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to access the starting time stamp by tracing command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34088956/unable-to-access-the-starting-time-stamp-by-tracing-command)

Comment: look for session table in system_traces keyspace